# Which is more productive: one global event listener or several of the same type in each component?

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

This mixin is used on almost every page, sometimes in multiple components.

```
data: () => ({
    device: {
        mobile: false,
        tablet: false,
        tabletLand: false,
        notepad: false
        desktop: false
    }
}),
mounted () {
    this.onResize()

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
},
destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
},
methods: {
    onResize () {
        const w = window.innerWidth

        this.device.mobile = w < 767
        this.device.tablet = w < 1024
        this.device.tabletLand = w < 1239
        this.device.notepad = w < 1399
        this.device.desktop = w >= 1400
    }
}
```

The interpreter is so smart that I shouldn't think about reusing mixins or is it better to register the mixin globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to be smart about. If you use this mixin in multiple components, the event will be handled in each of them (and each will have it's own `data` and methods) which is not optimal and wasteful

Better solution is to incorporate your code into your root Vue instance and use [provide/inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject) to share the data object with any component you want...

**btw** your code will not work correctly for `innerWidth === 1400`

Comment: Fixed. Why is this the best solution?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? It is better to run some code only once instead of multiple times...

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, you need something [like this](https://netbasal.com/reduce-change-detection-cycles-with-event-coalescing-in-angular-c4037199859f), only in Vue?

Comment: Welcome! I found this article but did not find one in Vue.